# How do I pass a variable from the parent scope to a child scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a partial page with code similar to the following:

```
<div class="selector-result row">
    <div ng-if="resultCtrl.result">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h4><strong>We Recommend:</strong></h4>
            <h2><strong>{{resultCtrl.result.Name}}</strong></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <div ng-controller="selectorResultCarouselController">
                    <div>
                        <div style="height: 305px">
                        <carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="false">
                            <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active" actual="slide">
                            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
                            </slide>
                        </carousel>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
...
```

I have a module that has a directive (selectorResult) with a controllerAs resultCtrl.  There is a controller in there too, selectorResultController, which  loads a variable 'results'.

What I'd like to do is get {{resultCtrl.result.AllImages}} into selectorResultCarouselController somehow so that I can add them to my carousel.  I'm lost.  I'm trying really hard to understand Angular, and I think I understand how the pieces work, I just am not understanding the system, if that makes sense.

I'm just looking for a little nudge here.  I've read and read and read, but I've not seen anything that is shining light on this problem.

Comment: angular's controllers have prototypical inheritance, so everything that you declare in parent controller will be available in child controllers. another option is to use factory/service.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid `$scope` confusion, consider using [AngularJS's controllerAs syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/). Basically, instead of attaching values to `$scope`, you attach them to the controller object itself. So:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrlOne', [function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = 'ctrlOne';
  }])
  .controller('ctrlTwo', [function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = 'ctrlTwo';
  }]);
```

and

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrlOne as one">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlTwo as two">
      <p>{{one.name}}</p> <!-- 'ctrlOne' -->
      <p>{{two.name}}</p> <!-- 'ctrlTwo' -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think I've seen the controllerAs demonstrated this succinctly before.  It makes more sense looking at it like this.

Answer (score 2):

Child scope inherits from the parent.  So just use $scope.result.AllImages.

Comment: I could swear I'd tried that, but I've tried so may things, I may have missed that one.

Comment: When I do var slides = $scope.result.AllImages inside my child controller, I get a Cannot read property 'AllImages' of undefined.

Comment: I got it working.  It was $scope.resultCtrl.result.AllImages.  I didn't realize that selectorResult was an isolated scope.

Answer (score 2):

> A "child scope" (prototypically) inherits properties from its parent scope.

from: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope.

In your case, in your child scope your variable is available as `$scope.result.Allmages`.

Answer (score 2):

If your directive has an isolate scope, you will have to bind it through attributes in your directive definition object (ddo). The attributes &, @, and = will allow you to do this.

```
scope { myAttribute: '@', myOtherAttribute: '&', myLastAttribute: '='}
```

And in your directive you would use something like:

```
<my-directive my-attribute="someString" my-other-attribute="someCallbackOnControllerScope()" my-last-attribute="somePropertyOnControllerScopeYouWantToBindTwoWays">
```

Please note that if you use the '@', it will passed as a string and you will have to parse it against the parent scope to turn it into an object (in the directive's post-link function):

```
$parse(myAttribute)(scope.$parent)
```

Otherwise your ddo can have a scope property set to false, in which case it will use the parent scope.

If you have a scope property set to true in the ddo you can still address the parent scope property (by referencing it as if you had no child scope/as if it were in that same scope already available), though be careful if you do this (scope: true) and have multiple of the same directives... As they will all share the same scope and thus override each other.

Please check this page out for more information: [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

I hope this was helpful